# Computer took much longer than normal to boot, and now windows open and close slow

Tags: windows-7, boot, audio, performance

I've got a Sager laptop, a GeForce GTX 680M, an i7, 32GB of RAM, and I'm running Windows 7. My computer recently began to make that sound Windows makes when you plug in or unplug something (The da duh thing. Not sure how else to describe it.) out of the blue, and very often. Easily 10 times a minute on average. I wasn't sure what was going on so I restarted my computer in hopes that might fix it, and when it began to reboot, it did so MUCH slower than it ever has before. In addition, anything I open and close does so very slowly, fading in/out over a period of seconds. I restarted it again, and thought it booted up slightly faster than before, I'm still having the same issues. The sound isn't playing anymore though, thank god. What's going on here?

Comment: I suspect that some task is running in the background and eating up your CPU and RAM.

Comment: Just checked that. Task manager says CPU usage is at ~20% and the memory thing says 4.7GB

Comment: Sometimes Task Manager lies.

Comment: Where should I look then? And what for?

Comment: Install [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: Says CPU usage is ~3%. Can't find any processes that seem out of the ordinary either. Could this be a hardware problem, maybe? Also, thanks for replying, and helping me out. I appreciate it.

Comment: It may be that you have a "floating" interrupt or some such.  If you use a hardwired Internet cable rather than WiFi, make sure your WiFi adapter is still turned ON.  Plug something (eg, a memory stick) into each USB port and remove it (with appropriate removal protocol).  For "occupied" ports, remove and reinstall the device.  Then "sleep" your unit for a minute or so, to reset interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CPU and HDD variables via SpeedFan program and compare them with maximum values from your hardware specification, which you can find on vendor websites. 
Also, run a virus check with some antivirus, for example AVAST

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you some tips.(Before that please tell that do you use any antivirus or optimization tools)

1. If your C drive is fully loaded try to delete some unnecessary files and make some free space. Also use the 'Disk Clean Up' from the Properties of C drive.
2. Also from the Properties of C dive try the tools and do an error checking and disk de-fragmentation.
3. If you don't have an antivirus try to use one and I suggest Avast(you can use any you want). Viruses and malwares cause your computer to behave strangely.
4. Try to use some softwares like Tune Up Utilities 2014, Advanced System Care 7 or C-Cleaner. These will help to solve common issues related with your system.